# Wrong behaviour of javascript applied to html5 numeric fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to web development, and I got an error when trying to apply a fairly simple javascript code.
Suppose that we have two numeric **html5** fields:

```
<label for="f1">First field</label>
            <input type="number" name="f1" id="f1" min="0" step="1" value="100"/>

<label for="f2">Second field</label>
            <input type="number" name="f2" id="f2" min="0" step="1" value="100"/>
```

Now I want to apply two simple rules for these fields.

When value of the first field changed, then this value (from first field) sets to the second field:

```
$("#f1").bind("change paste keyup", function()  {
    $("#f2").val($("#f1").val());  });
```

This works well.

The value of the second field can't exceed the value of the first field:

```
$("#f2").bind("change paste keyup", function()  {
    var f1_ = $("#f1").val();
    var f2_ = $("#f2").val();
    var f2_new = (f2_ > f1_)? f1_ : f2_;
    $("#f2").val(f2_new);  });
```

It works with some bugs - when the value of the second field is 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ..., and I try to decrease it, new value becomes equal to the value of the first field. 
[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/530/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the input type is number, the type of the value returned from .val() is a string.  To fix this, just convert back to a number by using `Number(f1_)` and `Number(f2_)`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bAZ7/2/) is a fiddle. See that before the conversion, the `console.log( typeof f1_ )` line logs `string`.

```
$("#f1").bind("change paste keyup", function() 
{
    $("#f2").val($("#f1").val()); 
});

$("#f2").bind("change paste keyup", function() 
{
    var f1_ = $("#f1").val();
    var f2_ = $("#f2").val();
    console.log( typeof f1_ );
    var f2_new = (Number(f2_) > Number(f1_))? f1_ : f2_;
    $("#f2").val(f2_new); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to put the `+` symbol in front of a String to convert it to a Number. See the following fix: http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/531/